# Consuming a Dynamics GP Wevservice with PHP

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to consume a .NET Web Service for M/S Dynamics GP (which
used to be Great Plains) and getting soap fault " Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'GetCashReceiptByKey'" 
[Soap Fault Message] => The specified type is abstract: name='OrganizationKey

Following are my pseudo code:

```
$options = array('login'     => 'loginid',
                'password'   => 'pwd',
                'trace'      => TRUE,
                'exceptions' => TRUE);

$wsdl = 'http://domain/DynamicsGPService.asmx?WSDL';

$client = new SoapClient ($wsdl, $options);

try
{
    $key = array('key' => array('Id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'));
    $company_key = array('Id' => 1);
    $context = array('Context' => array('CurrencyType' => 'Transactional',
                                        'OrganizationKey' => $company_key));
$param = array_merge($key, $context);
$res = $client->GetCashReceiptByKey($param);
}
catch(SoapFault $soapFault)
{
    echo htmlentities($soapFault);
}
```

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong here